# Scanning Across VPN, Files become corrupt.

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, site-to-site-vpn

So here is the situation. Previously, the organization I work for had 3 sites, A, B, and C. The sites were connected Via Site-to-Site VPN. There was one domain controller at site A which was also a file server (i know, i inherited it this way.). Site A is being discontinued, so I created two domain controllers, one each at sites B and C. File Services have been moved to its own server located at site B.

We have three Ricoh multifunction copier/scanners at Site B, and one at Site C. All of them were / are set up to scan to each user's respective home folder. After spinning up the new DCs and using robocopy to move all folders / files and doing all the other things involved with retiring the site A server, everything at site B is working fine; all scanners can scan normally.

The Issue: The single scanner at Site C cannot successfully scan to the file server at site B. Communication is successful, but the PDF is always corrupt. Sometimes, the file will be sent 3 times, with two being corrupt, and the third making it through in tact. The scanner is configured to use the on-site (C) DNS server. Drive maps to the file server are normal, and no other issues have presented themselves. The old site A server was 2008 R2, and all new servers are 2012R2.

What I've tried: scanning to other servers at site B. All with the same result EXCEPT for the site B domain controller. (which eliminates network firewalls, in my opinion). A ricoh tech suspected the copier's hard drive may be failing, so he replaced it to no avail. The firmware is also totally up to date. I've tried with different user credentials, etc, all have the same outcome. On the copier, there is an option to test the connection to the configured folder, which succeeds without issue.

If anyone has any thoughts on this, they would be most appreciated!!! Thank you in advance for the help.﻿

Comment: define `corrupt`.

Comment: When opening the PDF i receive the message "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Comment: Is it just the communications from the copier at site C that is exhibiting the issue? Can other devices at site C communicate over the VPN without errors?

Comment: Yes, other devices are functioning normally... users can access file shares, etc. between sites. I can browse to the share I'm trying to scan to without issue. Also, hyper-v replica is running between the sites without issue.

Comment: did you tried simply to scan to a share at the same site c ? can be a share on a normal os for the test. did you try to send it via ftp to site b ? or via scan to email ?

Comment: Long shot, but can you check what MTU size the copier is using (assuming it can be modified)? I've come across one VPN box that behaved badly when trying to wrap LAN packets when those packets were larger than could be safely wrapped and forwarded over the WAN. Given you inherited the site configuration, it might be something to check.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! will definitely check these things... to both - i succeeded at scanning accross the VPN, but only to the domain controller on the other site. wouldn't this eliminate all of these things? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you would think so given a successful scan to your remote DC. Without knowing your exact configuration (are you using VPN appliances, relying on the DC's own VPN, etc.) we are really poking around in the dark.

Comment: @punderwood yes and no, could be an antivirus that corrupt the file on the other server. As you got a DC on all site, why you don't scan locally to site-C and use DFS to sync that back at site-B ? I ask as you can control the bandwidth used that way, unlike in direct SMB transfert.

Answer (score -1):

I have worked with Ricoh and HP and copiers, in my case we are using SMB protocol to send files to the users share folder on the server. We do have a single account that has permission to access all the users shares.
As long as this account used to send the files to the shares have access, this should work but I have seen that people forgets that on Windows, the mentioned account MUST have "permission" on both the share (Sharing) and the Security tabs or it will not work.
I have tested my setup on Win2003 and 2008 R2, NOT tested on 2012 but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.